# Overwriting nested translations in I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

Say I have the following en.yml:

```
default_category: &default
  car:
    wheel: Wheel
    engine: Engine
    ...
    ...
    breaks: Breaks

some_other_category:
  <<: *default
```

What would be the best way to overwrite the word `breaks` without having to copy paste all the other translations?

**Tried so far:**

If you do this:

```
default_category: &default
  car:
    wheel: Wheel
    engine: Engine
    ...
    ...
    breaks: Breaks

some_other_category:
  <<: *default
  car:
    breaks: Super Breaks
```

All the other translations like `wheel` and `engine` are gone for `some_other_category` because I'am overwriting all translations for `car:`

If you do this:

```
default_category: &default
  car:
    wheel: Wheel
    engine: Engine
    ...
    ...
    breaks: Breaks

some_other_category:
  <<: *default
  car:
    wheel: Wheel
    engine: Engine
    ...
    ...
    breaks: Super Breaks
```

There's duplicate code due to copy/pasting.

The option to move the default pointer to the car is not really an option in my scenario.

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it myself, the solution is to add an extra pointer to car, not move the pointer.

```
default_category: &default
  car: &default_car
    wheel: Wheel
    engine: Engine
    ...
    ...
    breaks: Breaks

some_other_category:
  <<: *default
  car:
    <<: *default_car
    breaks: Super Breaks
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/bowsersenior/979804